# MapServer error : FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "..."

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis, mapserver, pg-hba.conf

I'm trying to run a MapServer 5/PostGIS installation on a Centos 6 virtual machine. 
I deployed MapServer in my cgi-bin folder, but now when I query (using firefox) mapserv file 
with the url `[virtual machine local IP]/cgi-bin/mapserv?MAP=/var/www/cgi-bin/[...]`, all I get is an image with the following error message on it :

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named '[name
>   of my layer]'.;msPostGISLayerOpen(): Query error. Database connection
>   failed (FATAL: ident authentification failed for user "foo") with
>   connect string 'user=foo dbname=foo password=foo host=localhost
>   port=5432'

I tried to change setting in pg_hba.conf with no luck.
foo database can be accessed with foo as sql user and foo as password using psql command.
What can I do ?

Comment: you run `psql` as same `OS` user as `MapServer` does?..

Comment: I'm running `psql foo -U foo` as root user, I don't know wich OS user is used by MapServer nor how to set it (I'm kind of new to UNIX).

Comment: from your answer I see os user does not matter :) password is ASCII only? no special characters?

Comment: The password is only a few lowercase letters (like `foo`). No numbers, no special chars.

Comment: do u have a `.pgpass` in home directory?... does it ask for the password when you `psql`?..

Comment: No .pgpass file anywhere, but psql does ask me for a password when I use `psql foo -U foo`

Comment: G! I must be blind! `ident` not `user`! look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accordong to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
change `ident` to `md5` for user `foo` in `hba.conf`

> Obtain the operating system user name of the client by contacting the
>   ident server on the client and check if it matches the requested
>   database user name. Ident authentication can only be used on TCP/IP
>   connections. When specified for local connections, peer authentication
>   will be used instead. See Section 19.3.5 for details.

you can check which hba you use by `psql` to your db and running `show hba_file ;`

Comment: I already have this line in pg_hba.conf :

`local   all      all     md5`

But it doesn't help.

Comment: from this error: `FATAL: ident authentification failed for user "foo"` you don't hit your line in hba.conf. is it the first in order?

Comment: Ok I found the answer. The problem was that I was looking for enabling access for a local access or a 127.0.0.1 host. Actually, I had to use the IPv6 localhost like this : `host   foo   foo   ::1/128   md5`. Thanks for your help :)